# UIButton created in code not working properly

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

So I've been holding off asking this question for a while because I know the solution will most likely be something very very simple. But I have come to the end of my tether so here goes:

I have created a UIButton programatically and linked it to a method, but it is not working!!

**.h definition**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CreaterPage : UIViewController
{
IBOutlet UIView *postcardView;
IBOutlet UIButton *returnButton;
}

-(void)goBack:(UIButton *)button;

@end
```

**.m definition**

```
#import "CreaterPage.h"

@implementation CreaterPage

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
NSLog(@"Creater Page View Loaded Successfully");
UIButton *goHomeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[goHomeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goBack:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[goHomeButton setTitle:@"Go Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
goHomeButton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100);
[self.view addSubview:goHomeButton];
}

-(void)goBack:(UIButton *)button
{
NSLog(@"Home");
}

@end
```

And basically, when I run the code, the button appears as defined but my program crashes whenever I press it.

In the main.m file, it gives me the error

> Thread 1: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".

On the line

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

I've tried all sorts and only turned to creating it programatically because I couldn't get it working through the interface builder.

So I'm hoping somebody on here can change my juvenile ways and show me where I'm going wrong :D

Thanks,

Matt

EDIT 1: Changed @selector(goBack) to @selector(goBack:)

Comment: just replace "@selector(goBack)" with "@selector(goBack:)"

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but I've already tried this and had no luck!! :D Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess would be that your action is defined as such:

```
[goHomeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goBack) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Note the `@selector(goBack)` without a colon following the method name. Your method in your `.m` file is defined as:

```
-(void)goBack:(UIButton *)button
```

So I imagine changing your action to `@selector(goBack:)` would clear things up.

**Sidenote:** It's very uncommon to define the type of the sender for an `IBAction`, as you have done. While you might not encounter any issues as long as your `UIButton` is the **only** UI object that causes the method to be called, it's very poor practice. You should change your method signature to:

```
-(IBAction)goBack:(id)sender
```

Note also the use of `IBAction` in place of `void`. While they're syntatically the same thing, the `IBAction` makes it clear to readers, and to Interface Builder, which methods are available for linking.

Comment: I'll admit, as soon as I saw your response I thought you'd nailed it right on the head, but unfortunately not!! Changed my action to @selector(goBack:) as you suggested, but I get exactly the same issue!!

Comment: @MatthewHallatt See my other point about the method signature. Maybe that will help?

Comment: Again, I've made your suggested changes but am still having no luck!! Just keeps giving me the same error :/   Matt

Comment: @MatthewHallatt You might want to turn on NSZombies (Google will show you how) as I imagine you've got a memory management issue somewhere in your code.

Comment: Ok, I'll check that out now. Thanks very much for all your help so far!! Really appreciate it!! :D   Matt

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
[goHomeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goBack) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

to

```
[goHomeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goBack:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Comment: Already changed this (see answer below) and it didn't help I'm afraid! Thanks for the answer and quick response though!! :D Matt